# How can I enter a string literal containing the dot character in XAML (Silverlight 4)?

Tags: .net, xaml, silverlight-4.0

Maybe this is something obvious, but here is what I have. I need to write a string in XAML. That is ok, but if the string has the dot character inside it, the XAML parser fails. I tried all kinds of escaping, but nothing helps.

```
            <datafilter:ItemPropertyDefinition Name="Players.Count"
                                               PropertyType="{Binding Int32, ElementName=Types}" 
                                               DisplayName="Squad Size">
            </datafilter:ItemPropertyDefinition>
```

No matter what I do, I cannot have a string literal that contains a dot. The XAML parser always tells:

"Players.Count' is not a valid value for Name".

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Rossen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the literal, it's the Name property.  You can't have a "." in Name, just as you can't name a variable with a "." in code.

In your example, accessing the DisplayName property would be written as: Players.Count.DisplayName, which wouldn't make sense.

The appropriate naming convention in your case would be, I think, PlayerCount.

Comment: That is not true. The Name is of type String. If I write this in code-behind and can do it and all is fine. Only XAML fails.

Comment: I can write this in C#:
itemPropertyDefinition.Name = "Player.Count";

Why not in XAML????

Comment: What does DisplayName have to do with Name??? Just ignore the other two properties. Think only about the the NAme property. It is of type STRING and I want to assign a STRING that contains the dot character. You do not care what i will do with it after that -- I just want to assign it. Do you know why I can or not?

Comment: I forgot to mention. The Name property is my property -- ItemPropertyDefinition is just my custom class.

Comment: I don't think the XAML parser cares that the property's on your class, I think it just cares that there's a property "Name" and it has rules for it.  I can't, for instance, change the Name property of a textbox to include a ".", either in XAML or in code.  My guess is if you change the name of the property, it will allow you to include the ".".

Comment: You are right. The parse does not care. I will change it to PropertyName and everything will be fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what is going on. It is amazing. Just a bad coincidence of naming.

ItemPropertyDefinition is my OWN class. It is a DependencyObject. It has a string DependencyProperty called Name. It is called Name because, well, it holds the Name of the thing.

Maybe the "clever" XAML parser does not allow dots in a Name property completely ignoring that fact that this is MY class and this is MY property.

I have to change this to be called PropertyName otherwise I am messing up DependencyObject.Name property.

Answer (score 0):

XAML gives special treatment to the names of elements using the `Name` and `x:Name` attribute. From [FrameworkElement.Name Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name.aspx):

> The string values used for Name have some restrictions, as imposed by the underlying x:Name Directive defined by the XAML specification. Most notably, a Name must start with a letter or the underscore character (_), and must contain only letters, digits, or underscores. For more information, see WPF XAML Namescopes.

In general you should avoid to define a `Name` property when defining a `FrameworkElement`.

Comment: ItemPropertyDefinition is a DependencyObject. It is not a FrameworkElement.